# UIBarButtonItem compiler error

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

Following a previous answer, I am implementing this piece of code to add a UIBarButtonItem to my viewController:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind target:self action:selector(backButton:)];
backButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

The error warning is:

```
Expected )
```

at backButton declaration line.

I have searched the internet to find the valid format of the declaration, but I think it is correct as it is now, but the compiler shows the error warning.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: It's `@selector`, not `selector`.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy, stupid question...if you want to put it as answer, you are welcome..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind target:self action:@selector(backButton:)];
backButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton;
```